# Why aren't women allowed in training camp?

Tags: nfl, training

Jeff Fisher cut Deon Long for bringing a woman to his dorm room. What's the big deal?

https://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2016/08/09/jeff-fisher-cut-deon-long-for-bringing-a-woman-to-his-camp-dorm-room/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article goes into this. Simply put, Jeff Fisher instituted a rule, and it was broken by Deon Long. The big deal is that a rule was broken.

> there was a strict no visitors policy in the team’s camp dorms at UC-Irvine ... Fisher listened to Long before telling him he’d broken a team rule that was non-negotiable.

I wouldn't apply this to other teams, or even "traning camp" as the article specifically mentions "team's camp dorms" (there's nothing to suggest that she wasn't allowed on-grounds during training camp). Any suggestion that this somehow disallows women from training camp (when the article clearly states "no visitors policy in the team’s camp dorms") is purely conjecture.